# Detect if floating point number is too big (overflow)

Tags: floating-point, overflow, mips, ieee-754, single-precision

I'm starting with MIPS and have been assigned a homework in which I have to find the hypotenuse of a triangle given its legs (all of them are single precision floating point numbers). However, in every step I have to check for overflow, by comparing the number with the IEEE754 representation for "infinite", but I don't know how to do that, and I would appreciate any help.

Edit: only code I have so far is for the inputs.

```
.text
main:
in1:    li $v0,4            #
        la $a0,inleg1       #message to request leg 1
        syscall             #
        li $v0,6            #read entered value as float
        syscall
        mov.s $f1,$f0       #move read value --> $f1=leg1

    #So now I have to include a condition to detect overflow, and show an error message and request the number again
    #The idea is to compare $f1 with infinity, and if it's not smaller, we have overflow
    #Then I have to repeat the evaluation after every operation performed
```

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Creating the +infinity floating-point number? Or doing the comparison of the value you have with infinity? Or something else? It would be helpful if you could show the code you have so far.

Comment: Load the infinity value into a floating-point register, use the `C.cond.fmt` instruction, followed by `BC1F` or `BC1T` (look up those instructions in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_).

Comment: @MarkDickinson I'm stuck at creating the +infinity floating-point number, so that I can compare my value $f1 with it and detect if there's overflow.

Comment: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: Solved, thank you all for your help!